# strdup non-dependent implementation (dumping malloc dependency)

Tags: c

I have a custom implementation for `_strdup`. It shouldn't have any dependencies, which means I cannot use CRT or anything built-in. The code below works fine. The only problem is that it depends on `malloc`. Therefore I can't use it with `/NODEFAULTLIB`, unless I implement my own malloc.

Any ideas for non-dependent implementations? Or at least a malloc/free implementation. I would even accept a shellcode implementation.

```cpp
size_t __strlen(const char* str)
{
    const char* s;

    for (s = str; *s; ++s)
        ;
    return (s - str);
}

void* __memcpy(void* to, const void* from, size_t count)
{
    register char* f = (char*)from;
    register char* t = (char*)to;
    register size_t i = count;

    while (i-- > 0)
        *t++ = *f++;
    return to;
}

char* __strdup(const char* str)
{
    size_t len;
    char* copy;

    len = __strlen(str) + 1;
    if (!(copy = (char*)malloc(len)))
        return nullptr;

    __memcpy(copy, str, len);
    return copy;
}
```

I found a broken malloc implementation:

```cpp
#define MEMORY_CAPACITY 20000

void* mov_sbrk(int increment)
{
    static char global_mem[MEMORY_CAPACITY] = { 0 };
    static char* p_break = global_mem;

    char* const limit = global_mem + MEMORY_CAPACITY;
    char* const original = p_break;

    if (increment < global_mem - p_break || increment >= limit - p_break)
    {
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return (void*)-1;
    }
    p_break += increment;

    return original;
}

//=======================================================================

#define ALIGNMENT 8
#define ALIGN(size) (((size) + (ALIGNMENT-1)) & ~(ALIGNMENT-1))

typedef struct list_t list_t;
struct list_t 
{
    unsigned    in_use : 1;     /* if the block is used or not */
    size_t      order;      /* current order of block (2^order) */
    list_t* succ;       /* right child block in tree */
    list_t* pred;       /* left child block in tree */
};

#define K_MAX 22
#define K_MAX_SIZE (1 << K_MAX)
#define ORDER_0 4
// Size of the node metadata
#define META_SIZE (ALIGN(sizeof(list_t)))

static list_t* find_block(size_t);
static size_t get_order(size_t);
static list_t* split(list_t*, size_t);

/* Array of pointers to first block of order k at free_list[k] */
static list_t* freelist[K_MAX + 1];
static void* start = NULL;

static void print_freelist()
{
    for (int i = ORDER_0; i <= K_MAX; i++) 
    {
        int f = 0;
        int j = 0;
        list_t* current = freelist[i];
        while (current)
        {
            if (!current->in_use) 
            {
                f++;
            }
            j++;
            current = current->succ;
        }
    }
}

void* malloc(size_t requested_size)
{
    print_freelist();

    if (requested_size <= 0)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (!start)
    {
        // First allocation ever, grab memory and root the tree
        start = mov_sbrk(K_MAX_SIZE);
        list_t* top = reinterpret_cast<list_t*>(start);
        top->order = K_MAX;
        top->in_use = 0;
        top->succ = NULL;
        top->pred = NULL;
        freelist[K_MAX] = top;
    }

    /* E.g. if requested size is 56 bytes, k = 6 (2^6=64)*/
    size_t k = get_order(ALIGN(requested_size + META_SIZE));

    list_t* r = find_block(k);

    if (r) {
        r->in_use = 1;
        print_freelist();
        return (r + 1);
    }
    else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

/* Find the smallest power of 2 larger than k */
static size_t get_order(size_t v)
{
    int k = ORDER_0;
    while ((1 << k) < v) {
        k++;
    }
    return k;
}

// finds a suitable block of order k. if not found return null
static list_t* find_block(size_t k)
{
    if (k > K_MAX)
        return NULL;

    list_t* current = freelist[k];

    while (current) {

        if (!current->in_use)
            return current;

        current = current->succ;
    }

    list_t* big_block = find_block(k + 1);
    if (big_block) {
        current = split(big_block, k);
    }

    return current;
}

static void remove_from_freelist(list_t* item)
{
    size_t k = item->order;

    if (freelist[k] == item)
        freelist[k] = item->succ;

    if (item->pred)
        item->pred->succ = item->succ;

    if (item->succ)
        item->succ->pred = item->pred;

    item->pred = NULL;
    item->succ = NULL;
}

static void add_to_freelist(list_t* item)
{
    size_t k = item->order;

    if (!freelist[k])
    {
        freelist[k] = item;
        item->succ = NULL;
        item->pred = NULL;
        return;
    }

    item->pred = NULL;
    item->succ = freelist[k];
    freelist[k]->pred = item;
    freelist[k] = item;
}

static list_t* split(list_t* src, size_t new_order)
{
    while (src->order > new_order)
    {
        /* src becomes left buddy */
        remove_from_freelist(src);

        // set new order
        src->order = src->order - 1;
        // calculate half size of old block, aka size of new order.
        size_t size = 1 << src->order;

        list_t* right = reinterpret_cast<list_t*>(src + size);
        right->order = src->order;
        right->in_use = 0;

        add_to_freelist(right);
        add_to_freelist(src);
    }

    return src;
}

static void merge(list_t* block)
{
    if (block->in_use || block->order == K_MAX)
        return;

    list_t* buddy = (list_t*)((uint64_t)start + (block - start) ^ (1 << block->order));

    if (buddy->in_use || buddy->order != block->order)
        return;

    list_t* left = block;
    list_t* right = buddy;
    if (block > buddy) {
        left = buddy;
        right = block;
    }

    remove_from_freelist(right);
    remove_from_freelist(left);
    left->order++;
    add_to_freelist(left);
    merge(left);
}


void free(void* ptr)
{
    print_freelist();

    if (!ptr)
        return;

    list_t* block = (((list_t*)ptr) - 1);

    block->in_use = 0;
    merge(block);

    print_freelist();
}

void* calloc(size_t nbr_elements, size_t element_size) 
{
    size_t size = nbr_elements * element_size;
    void* ptr = malloc(size);
    if (ptr == NULL)
        return NULL;
    memset(ptr, 0, size);
    return ptr;
}

void* realloc(void* ptr, size_t size)
{
    if (!ptr) {
        return malloc(size);
    }

    list_t* block = (((list_t*)ptr) - 1);
    if ((1 << block->order) - META_SIZE >= size) {
        return ptr;
    }

    void* new_ptr = malloc(size);
    if (!new_ptr) {
        return NULL;
    }

    memcpy(new_ptr, ptr, (1 << block->order) - META_SIZE);
    free(ptr);
    return new_ptr;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. The `strdup` function returns a pointer that you can later pass to `free`. If you don't have an implementation of `free`, you can't implement `strdup`. Do you need  a `malloc`/`free` implementation? If so, what are your requirements? If they're the same as the usual ones, then look at existing implementations.

Comment: The `brk` syscall is about the only way you can move the end of the data segment to achieve an allocation without `malloc`.  For 32-bit the call is `0x2d` for x86_64 it is `0xc`. I'm not sure if that will work for you, but worth looking at.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, yes. I'm asking for a malloc implementation. I did look at other implementations from freebsd linux, but it doesn't really help.

Comment: Note that the keyword `register` is really no help; the compiler ignores it.  C++ has actually removed it as a keyword in C++17 and later.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, thanks, I didn't know that.

Comment: For GNU C it is also worth keeping in mind [Reserved Words](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html) `"...reserved names include all external identifiers (global functions and variables) that begin with an underscore (‘_’) and all identifiers regardless of use that begin with either two underscores..."`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned `/nodefaultlib` option, seems like you are on Windows. Then instead of using `malloc()` you can directly use Windows API function `HeapAlloc()` and then `HeapFree()` to free copy of the string later. You may want to wrap them into you own `__malloc()` and `__free()`, like this:

```
void* __malloc(size_t size)
{
   return HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, size); 
}

void __free(void* p)
{
   if (p) HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, p); 
}
```